# How do you Store and load a TFIdf vectorizer using pickle?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pickle, jnlp, tfidfvectorizer

```
def custom1(input):
      List1=[] 
    for i in input:
        List1.append(i)
    return List1
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=custom1)
```

After fitting my vectorizer. I dump it however when i load my vectorizer it says that it cant find the module custom1. can someone please help or is there another way to load and save a vectorizer?

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'custom1' on main'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i do not get what your function is doing as it only copies an array to another one. Can you please specify that in more detail?

If you want to store something using pickle just call

```
pickle.dump(vectorizer, open("vectorizer.pickle", "wb"))
```

and to reload it in future you can use

```
vectorizer = pickle.load(open("vectorizer.pickle", "rb"))
```

To pickle a function i would recommend to use Cloudpickle

```
def custom1(input):
  return input

pickledfunction = cloudpickle.dumps(custom1)
pickle.loads(pickledfunction)([1,2,3])
```

Comment: the main objective of the function is to take a string and return a list of characters present in that string.  I used that pickle command to dump it. but when i restart the kernel and load it , it shows the above error.

Comment: see the main thing is when i use my jupyter notebook i have to run that cell containing the custom function first and then when i load the vectorizer it works. Im using this application in flask so ive copied the function and after copying it i load the model. it then gives the error custom1 cant be found.

Comment: So you basically can not just simply dump a function. It has to be serializable. Either you can wrap the function in a serializable class or use an python package which can help you to pickle functions. I would recommend to use https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle or https://pypi.org/project/dill/